# Loop, iterate with unexpected results, Propertie

Tags: loops, properties

```
package javaapplication43;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class JavaApplication43 {

    int totalResults = 45; //
    int itemsperPage = 10;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;

    FileOutputStream output = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream input=null;

    public JavaApplication43() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("totalResults", "45");
        prop.setProperty("itemsperPage", "10");
        prop.setProperty("?", "?");

        // save properties to project root folder
        prop.store(output, null);

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("totalResults"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("itemsperPage"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("?"));

    }

    public void makeLoop() {
        for (i = 1; i <= (totalResults / itemsperPage) + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("nextPage " + i);
            for (; j < i * itemsperPage; j++) {
                if (j > totalResults) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Filenumber " + (j + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JavaApplication43 myTest = new JavaApplication43();
        myTest.makeLoop();
    }
}
```

*This Code gives the Result:

- nextPage1: Filnumber1, Filnumber2...Filenumber10
- nextPage2: Filenumber11, Filenumber12.., Filenumber20
- nextPage5: Filenumber41, Filenumber42.., Filenumber46

And so on. I expect the result so, if i start the next time with a sheduller it should start
with the nextpage2 and print the files from 11-20,

if i start again the programm it should start with the nextpage 3 and print the files from 21-30 and so on depends on the value wich i have for totalResults.

The Solution is may to save the value in the Property to make it Persistent, so that 
if i  run the Programm again, it will read the Property config.properties to start on the right index, but i dont know how to iterate, through the loop. ?

Comment: Why do you expect that? You *start* by writing fresh values to the properties file.

Comment: The Loop should stop after the first Page and should save this Value in to the Property File. If i run the Programm it should start if the 2 Page ? I dont know how to solve??

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class JavaApplication43_with_Main_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int totalResults = 45; //
        int itemsperPage = 10;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream input = null;
        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");


        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);


        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println("nextPage Prop " + prop.getProperty("nextPage"));

        String nextPage = prop.getProperty("nextPage");
        int intNextPage = Integer.parseInt(nextPage);
        System.out.println("intNextPage " + intNextPage);

        for (i = intNextPage; i <= (totalResults / itemsperPage) + 1; i++) {
            int jNextPage=intNextPage-1;
            System.out.println("nextPage here " + i);
            for (j=jNextPage*itemsperPage; j < i * itemsperPage; j++) {
               // System.out.println("j ist "+j);
                if (j > totalResults) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Filenumber " + (j + 1));
            }
            String strI = "" + (i + 1);
            System.out.println("hello " + strI);
            output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
            prop.setProperty("nextPage", strI);
            prop.store(output, null);
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

*This is the does make loop and printing out*

- nextPage 1, Filenumber1,Filenumber2,..,Filenumber10

then it saves the nextPage value into the Property File.

If you start again, it does printing out

- nextPage 2, Filenumber11,Filenumber12,...,Filenumber20

You should have e Propertiy File with the Name, config.properties
and but the key nextPage and the value 1, nextPage=1;--->config.properties